# Vuex display error message(and unset) on navigation guard redirect

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

In my Vue Router I use a global **navigation guard** to check if a query String is required(`to.meta.query`) for the requested route - if none is provided or if it's value is null, **redirect to parent component & dispatch an error**.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.query) {
    let query = to.query;
    let exists = Object.keys(query).filter(function (key) {
      return query[key] !== null && query[key] !== ''
    })
    if (to.meta.query && exists.length < 1) {
        let error = {
          to: to.name,
          type: "query"
        }
        store.commit('redirectError', error);
        next({ name: 'Search', replace:true})
    }
  }
  next()
})
```

In my parent component 'Search' I included my error Component which **calculates the error message** based on "to" and "type" of the error object retrieved from the store:

```
computed: {
  error: function () {
    if (!isEmpty(this.$store.state.error)) {
      this.errorTo = this.$store.state.error.to;
      this.errorMessage = this.calcErrorMessage();

      this.$store.commit('dispatchError', null);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
},
```

and then **display the error itself using v-model**;

```
<b-alert variant="danger" dismissible v-model="error">
  {{errorMessage}}
</b-alert>
```

How can I achieve `error` being "kind of reactive". So when I change the route to another child-component the error disappears?
My component structure:

```
Search: (parent)
  -SearchForm
  -SearchResult
  -SearchDetail
```

### Edit:

Put everything in own errorComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Error component

In my case, if the query params of a certain route is missing (having meta.query set to true), a error object will be saved in the `store`;

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 if(to.meta.query) {
  let query = to.query;
  let exists = Object.keys(query).filter(function (key) {
    return query[key] !== null && query[key] !== ''
  })
    if ((to.meta.query && exists.length < Object.keys(query).length) || (exists < 1)) {
       let error = {
         to: to.name,
         type: "query"
       }
       store.commit('dispatchError', error);
       next({ name: 'Search', replace:true})
   }
 } 
 next()
})
```

While still using *Vuex* I put everything in a separate error component;

```js
computed: {
  error: function () {
    if (!isEmpty(this.$store.state.error)) {
      this.errorTo = this.$store.state.error.to;
      this.errorMessage = this.calcErrorMessage();

      this.$store.commit('dispatchError', null);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
},
```

In the components computed function I check if a error has been dispatched - after reading it, it will be reset (to improve this, it could also done using Vuex getters). `calcErrorMessage` returns the error text based on the content of the error-object in the store.

*If you know any improvement to this method I'd be very thankful*

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the error on your error component

```
created () {
 this.error = store.state.error;
 this.errorTo = store.state.redirectError.to;
 this.errorMessage = this.calcErrorMessage();

 //reset error
 store.commit('redirectError', null)
},
```

and probably also reset in on the guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 if(to.meta.query) {
  let query = to.query;
  let exists = Object.keys(query).filter(function (key) {
    return query[key] !== null && query[key] !== ''
  })
  if (to.meta.query && exists.length < 1) {
    let error = {
      to: to.name,
      type: "query"
    }
    store.commit('redirectError', error);
    next({ name: 'Search', replace:true})
  }
 }
 // reset error
 store.commit('redirectError', error);
 next()
})
```

Comment: I put everthing in a seperate component now. The key problem stays the same - I need 'error' to be reactive. Otherwise the error message will not disappear if the $route changes to other child components. (error is displayed in Parent 'Search' component).
If I reset the error before next() - It will be reset automatically as soon as the route changes to the component I'm redirecting to (global navigation guard)